# Number of coins of integer weights

Tags: logic, contest-math, puzzle

> $A$ tells $B$ : "I could be visiting you on any day in the next two months and you must give me gold coins of as much total weight in grams as the number of days that would elapse from today."  If gold coins are available in integer gram weights, what is the least number of coins with which $B$ can meet $A$'s demand on any day?

> $(1)$ $31$

> $(2)$ $7$

> $(3)$ $6$

> $(4)$ $13$

How to approach this problem? Can anybody shed some light on it? Thanks for your time.

**Source** $:$ CSIR NTA NET DECEMBER $2019.$

Comment: 6 Coins with weights 1 gram, 2 grams, 4 grams, 8 grams, 16 grams, and 32 grams.

Comment: @SenZen why do you take $32\ $?

Comment: I don't see any meaningful ambiguity in the meaning of "two months".  We are sure that "two months" must mean at least $28+31$ days and at most $31+31$ and both of those are $>32$ while neither of those exceed $63$, so....

Comment: @lulu it may so happen $A$ told this to $B$ on $1$st March. Then he may come to $31$st May. Then the total number of days elapsed is $91.$

Comment: @Phibetakappa  Ah, I see.  Yes.  In that case we do need the $64$ coin.  I like the problem better, though, if you don't allow this.  It's an interesting coincidence that $62$ is just shy of $64$.  With your reading, it isn't close. $3\times 31$ is nowhere near $128$.

Comment: @cosmo5 suppose if $B$ gives him ($A$) a single coin weighing $91$ grams. Why isn't it permissible? Why should $B$ always have to give him coins of weight $2^n\ $?

Comment: @cosmo5 my question is $:$ Why should $B$ always have to give him $(A)$ coins of weight $2^n\ $? Why can't $B$ give a single coin to $A$ weighing $91$ grams. Then single coin will suffice.

Comment: Because other sets of numbers will miss some numbers. What if he comes on 50th day? You don't have 50 coin.

Comment: @cosmo5 I don't get your point. Sorry. If he $(A)$ comes on $50$th day $B$ will give $A$ a single coin weighing $50$ grams. Because coins of integer weight is available by hypothesis.  What's the problem in that?

Comment: @Phibetakappa, are you keeping every coin 1,2..,91? You have to keep least number of coins.

Comment: @Phibetakappa If "the next two months" includes May, then it should *exclude* March. IMHO. If A said (on the 1st of March) "I could be visiting you on any day in the next month" I'd expect to see him in March, but the wording is a little ambiguous, so it's feasible that means he'll be visiting in April instead of March.

Comment: @cosmo5 yeah this logic sounds good to me. But what if we give coins of weight $3^n\ $?

Comment: $3^n$ only works if A can give change (also using $3^n$ coins).

Comment: @PM2Ring $2^n$ doesn't also work in my example ($1$st March to $31$st May).

Comment: I want to report this puzzle to the Association Against Calendric Ambiguities, who meet biannually. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh! God. Then will I be punished for posting that? This is not the question I made. This question appeared in CSIR NTA NET $2019$ in the month of December. Believe me sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116467/discussion-between-phi-beta-kappa-and-pm-2ring).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Any positive integer can be written as sum of powers of $2$. Every decimal number has a (unique) binary (base-$2$) representation.